# Class run every time from ServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a package which runs fine. In my service provider I do things like binding of interfaces and setting up config files. I have a class elsewhere in my project that I want to run every time (and not as middleware).

What is the 'clean' way to invoke a class in my ServiceProvider so it runs every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say to run your code in the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider`.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php#L14